# How to import a class file in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a class in a file (TestClass.Groovy) and I want to import it in my Jenkins script. I've tried the **load** function, but it gives me the error :

---

> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods print java.lang.Object

---

Example of the call of the load function :

---

```
def Test = load 'Z:\\TestClass.Groovy'
Test.PTest()
```

---

Can someone help me ? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into script approval and allow that method to be run. It's just blocking it.

Go to Manage Jenkins->In Process Script Approval